# Add sites in subdomain and not under wordpress multisite subdomain

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I'm confused, I have a miltisite wordpress installation but also another site managing the customer areas.
So I have the site on the main domain [www.domaine.com](http://www.domaine.com) and i installed the wordpress multisite in a subdomain: sites.domain.com

So far everything is fine, but when I want to create a site, wordpress requires me to be subject to the subdomain like this: other.site.domain.com

I tried to modify the .htaccess and wp-config.php but when I go back to the site management it redirects me to [www.domaine.com](http://www.domaine.com) without my being able to access the wordpress multisite management...

How can I create sites with addresses under the domain and not under the subdomain like this:
other.domain.com and not like this other.site.domain.com

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's ok, I can't access for two reasons.

One my wildcard is set on other folder than wp installation (blank page on subsite create)

Two I need to set address of new site for replace domain.com/other to other.domain.com

And now I can access to website and subsite.

Thank!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer, I just tested but it does not react correctly.
When I put the configuration of `DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE` on domaine.com I can no longer access the settings of the multisite network, I am redirected to the purchase site which is on the domain.

Another thing, if I therefore create a site in a subdirectory and not in a subdomain with the `SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL` configuration false, when I type `test.domaine.com` a blank page appears as if there was no site or if I Type `site.domain.com/test/` it works.

I cleared the caches everywhere and tried again but nothing happened.

In case I expressed myself badly,
`www.domain.com` = The commercial site of the company
`site.domain.com` = Multisite management and sample site
`other1.domain.com` = Customer site created from site.domain.com

thanks again